# Creating a dropdown menu in uisearchbar

Tags: ios, xcode, uisearchbar

I am building an ios app and the app has a uisearchbar. The entry in the Search bar must be precise, so I want to add a drop down menu that has the list of accurate data(that is obtained online, once the person hits "search"). How would I be able to add such a thing?

Comment: U can add a `UITableView` programatically and show and hide it according to your need.